# Flutter App restarts when I try to change its state (changing Locale)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on an app that needs to do stuff before letting the user use it, namely fetch the phone's language and fetch an online file that contains information to display daily.

So now that I've done the whole fetching locale language part, I thought it would be the perfect moment to add the loading animation to display while we fetch the infos. I used a FutureBuilder and it looks fine.

I do have a problem though. When I change the language, it restarts the whole app (with the loading screen and all) and resets to original language because it also executes the app initialization part.

Here's the code, any help is much appreciated !

```
const en = Locale('en', 'UK');
const fr = Locale('fr', 'FR');
const ja = Locale('ja', 'JA');
var currentLocale = en;
bool localInit = false;

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();

  static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale newLocale) async {
    _MyAppState? state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>();
    state!.changeLanguage(newLocale);
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void changeLanguage(Locale newLocale) {
    setState(() {
      currentLocale = newLocale;
    });
  }

//this part is the one I use to fetch the phone's Locale

  Future<int> initLoc() async {
    Locale res;
    String? localeCode;
    try {
      localeCode = await Devicelocale.currentLocale;
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Error obtaining current locale");
    }

    switch (localeCode) {
      case 'fr':
        res = fr;
        break;
      case 'ja':
        res = ja;
        break;
      default:
        res = en;
    }
    currentLocale = res;
    localInit = true;
    await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    return 1;
  }
```

and finally the build method:

```
return FutureBuilder(
        future: initLoc(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: SpinKitRotatingCircle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  size: 50.0,
                ),
              );
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("Error loading locale data: ${snapshot.error}");
              } else {
                return MaterialApp(
                  locale: currentLocale,
                  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out with some help!

The problem here is that the `future` is defined within the build method. So  to fix it, 2 steps needs to be taken:

1. Declaring a Future in the app state
2. Initializing this new attribute by calling the initLoc function in `initState`

Here's what it looks like:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<int> _loc;

  void changeLanguage(Locale newLocale) {
    setState(() {
      currentLocale = newLocale;
    });
  }

  Future<int> initLoc() async {...
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loc = initLoc();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _loc,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) { ...
```

And that's it! Note I needed to use `late` when declaring this new variable since I know it's gonna be initialized !